# Слетают стили jQuery и CSS при добавлении в таблицу.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. Есть палагин DataTables для работы с таблицами.

Вот сайт палагина https://www.datatables.net/.

Я установил его на свой сайт и таблица заработала.

Таблица создается в JS файле функцией table_of_goods();

Данные таблицы выводятся в столбцы: Товар 1, Цена с помощью цикла, который забирает информацию из массива test[];

Изначально я прописал в массиве следующие значения test[1, 2, 3]; И эти значения выводятся в поле Товар. Все работает.

Перестает все работать, когда я добавляю значение в массив из формы. Стили и jQuery сразу отключаются. При этом все добавляется, но без стилей и примочек типа поиска по таблице, которые добавляет палагин. Подскажите, в чем проблема? Ниже коды HTML и JS файла.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Goods</title>
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


    <style>
    .bloc {background-color: #ffffff; padding: 20px;}
    .head_add {text-align: right;}
    .tab {margin-top: 50px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

   <div class="container bloc">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- 1 -->
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <form class="form-inline">
  <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Name</label>

  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"  id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="What are you looking for ?">


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 head_add"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</button></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 tab">
  <div id="table"></div>
 </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 tab">

  <form id="add_form" class="form-inline" onsubmit="return table_of_goods()">

  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"  id="good" placeholder="Good">
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"  id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Count">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"  id="price" placeholder="Price">

  <input id="add_update" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var test = [1,2,3];


function table_of_goods () {
    var good = '';
    var price;
    good = document.getElementById("good").value;
    var check = good.length;
    price = document.getElementById("price").value;

if (check > 0) {
    test.push([[good],[price]]);
    };


var elem = document.getElementById('table');

var table = '<table id=main_table class=display cellspacing=0 width=100%><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Price, $</th><th>Actions</th></tr><tfoot><tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Actions</th></tfoot><tbody>';


for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
table += '<tr><td>' + test[i] + '</td><td>495</td><td>Действия</td></tr>';
}


table += '</tbody></table>';

el.value = '';

el2.value = '';

el3.value = 'Add';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main_table').DataTable();
} );

elem.innerHTML = table;

return false;
}

table_of_goods();
```

Comment: сча попробую помочь, юзаю этот же плагин

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не в том месте инициализировался плагин на таблице, надо после её создания, должно быть так:

```
    elem.innerHTML = table;

    $('#main_table').DataTable();
```

```js
var test = [1, 2, 3], good, price, elem, table, i, testLength;

function renderTable() {

    good = $("#good").val();
    price = $("#price").val();

    if (good.length > 0) {
        test.push([[good], [price]]);
    }

    table = '<table id="main_table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Price, $</th><th>Actions</th></tr><tfoot><tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Actions</th></tfoot><tbody>';

    testLength = test.length;

    for (i = 0; i < testLength; i++) {
        table += '<tr><td>' + test[i] + '</td><td>495</td><td>Действия</td></tr>';
    }

    table += '</tbody></table>';

    elem = $('#table');
    elem.html(table);

    $('#main_table').DataTable({"searching": true});

    return false;
}

renderTable();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Goods</title>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <style>
        .block {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="table"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <form id="add-form" class="form-inline" onsubmit="return renderTable()">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="good" placeholder="Good">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="another-input" placeholder="Count">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Price">
                <input id="add-update" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Я на скорую руку не перебирал ваш код, но советую его упорядочить, чтобы все было грамотно, так он трудночитаемый и с ошибками.

Comment: Спасибо вам, большое! Был бы, конечно, очень признателен, если бы указали на ошибки и как правильно.

Comment: Я убрал лишнюю ерунду. id у инпутов не могут дублироваться по спецификации, переменные объявляем до цикла (так принято, чтобы интерпритатор не резервировал их в цикле много раз). Для поиска по таблице у плагина есть опция : {"searching": true} . Скрипты принято в верстке подключать в конце файла, чтобы не тормозить отрисовку страницы. Названия функций советуют писать осмысленные, например renderTable(); - отрисовать таблицу. Кстати, названия функций принято обычно писать "камелКейсом".

Comment: Ну ещё я не правил форму добавления строки в таблицу, по логике она должна ещё и стоимость менять, а не захаркоженно ставить 495. Но это уже ваша логика.

Comment: если вам помогло, отметьте ответ как правильный

Comment: Поставил. Спасибо!